# PHP: compute 2 variables product

Tags: php

how can I compute the product between these 2 quantities in php ?

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't work

```
<?php echo (uc_price($price_info, $context) * $product->qty); ?>
```

thanks

Comment: where does `uc_price` come from, add more details, are you using some sort of framework or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does uc_price($price_info, $context)  and $product->qty return a integer? its more likely that uc_price($price_info,$context) return a array, object or something else. make sure it return a integer. 
Also its better to cast those value into integer/float before multiplication e.g:

```
<?php echo (int)uc_price($price_info,$context) * (int)$product->qty; ?>
```

or cast them to float(price is more likely to be float:

```
<?php echo (float)uc_price($price_info,$context) * (float)$product->qty; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Echo the variables to determine if they're numbers:

```
<?php
  echo "<br>" . uc_price($price_info, $context) . "<br>" . $product->qty;
?>
```

Then debug your code(check the part(s) that does not return a number).